# Android 6.0 Marshmallow Bluetooth SpeechRecognizer mic not working

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-bluetooth

Is anyone else having an issue where the speechrecognizer won't hear speech when using Bluetooth?  This started i believe with Marshmallow.  The recognizer works perfect without bluetooth on and has worked great in previous versions with BT.  Any suggestions?  Could it be permissions?  I don't believe Bluetooth or Bluetooth_admin need to be manually accepted.  Let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is Permission. You should request Bluetooth Permission at Runtime. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35607833/3226984)

Comment: i have it requested in the manifest just not explicitly like 6.0 requires.  It doesn't appear to be on the dangerous permission list.

Comment: It should be requested in the code before using Bluetooth features.

Comment: I don't believe that is the case. As proof i ran the following and the results were that I have rights.    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH); and int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN);